# Creating PrePopulated Allocation Table in R

Tags: r

~~~~~~~~~
UPDATE - Thanks! I should have been more specific in my original question. I'm trying to create an allocation table to use in a portfolio optimization program. So the columns would be securities and each row is a different allocation. Each row has to add up to 1 (or 100%) and I'd like to be able to specify the increments. So for example, if there are three securities and I want the increment to be 1%, the first row could be 98%, 1%, 1%. The next row could be 97%, 1%, 2% and so on. In the end I'd have a large table with every possible allocation combination (based on a specified interval). Does that help? 
~~~~~~

I am looking to create an allocation table in R and I've hit a wall.  I've researched this problem in multiple books and websites and can't seem to find a straight-forward approach.

In the most basic form, I am looking to generate a table that is similar to the one below.

Assuming that there are only three variables and each row must add up to 1.

```
    v1   v2   v3 v1...v2...v3
1 0.25 0.25 0.50            1
2 0.25 0.50 0.25            1
3 0.50 0.25 0.25            1
4 0.75 0.25 0.00            1
5 0.75 0.00 0.25            1
6 1.00 0.00 0.00            1
7 0.50 0.25 0.25            1
8 0.25 0.25 0.50            1
```

Ideally, I'd like to return a matrix.  I've had no luck so far using R to do this.  Can anyone help me out?  I'm not even sure where to start.

Thank you very much,

Andrew

Comment: Do you want to generate just this one instance, or a general solution?  What are the logic rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A deterministic approach:

If you want all possible combinations in `n` variables that are nonnegative, sum to 1 and divide the interval `[0,1]` in `s` equal parts, you can use the following code:

First a function that gives the permutations of `n` integers that sum to `s`:

```
perms <- function(n, s)
{
    if(n==1) return(matrix(s,nrow=1,ncol=1))

    do.call(rbind, lapply(0:s, function(i) cbind(perms(n-1, s-i), i, deparse.level=0)))
}
```

Now define the number of columns and the number of "cuts", and rescale:

```
> perms(3,4)/4
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,] 1.00 0.00 0.00
 [2,] 0.75 0.25 0.00
 [3,] 0.50 0.50 0.00
 [4,] 0.25 0.75 0.00
 [5,] 0.00 1.00 0.00
 [6,] 0.75 0.00 0.25
 [7,] 0.50 0.25 0.25
 [8,] 0.25 0.50 0.25
 [9,] 0.00 0.75 0.25
[10,] 0.50 0.00 0.50
[11,] 0.25 0.25 0.50
[12,] 0.00 0.50 0.50
[13,] 0.25 0.00 0.75
[14,] 0.00 0.25 0.75
[15,] 0.00 0.00 1.00
```

Comment: Ferdinand, quick question.  in the cbind call, it has f(n-1, s-i) as the first argument.  Is this supposed to be c(n-1, s-i)?  I think this is exactly what I was trying to do--but when I run the code, it only returns 2 columns.  What I am missing here?

Comment: @AndrewMatuszak, sorry, it was a typo. The function is recursive, I've replaced `f` for `perms`.

Comment: Ah!  That is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you again.  Great, concise code.

Answer (score 2):

#### Updated answer based on comment

It sounds like what you are looking for is a way to generate permutations. In that case, try `permutations` from the "gtools" package. First, generate *all* permutations, then select only those where the rows sum to 100.

```
> ## install.packages(gtools)
> library(gtools)
> x <- permutations(101, 3, 0:100, repeats.allowed=TRUE)
> y <- x[rowSums(x) == 100, ]
> head(y)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0  100
[2,]    0    1   99
[3,]    0    2   98
[4,]    0    3   97
[5,]    0    4   96
[6,]    0    5   95
> tail(y)
        [,1] [,2] [,3]
[5146,]   98    0    2
[5147,]   98    1    1
[5148,]   98    2    0
[5149,]   99    0    1
[5150,]   99    1    0
[5151,]  100    0    0
```

#### Original answer

Hopefully I'm not oversimplifying, but maybe you can try something like this. You don't specify whether negative numbers should be included or not. I've assumed not.

Create a small function that uses one of R's random number generator. I have used `runif` in my function. The function arguments include the number of columns you want (I've set the default at 3), the minimum, and maximum value.

```
myFun <- function(n = 3, min = 0, max = 1) {
  temp <- runif(n = n, min = min, max = max)
  temp/sum(temp)
}
```

Use `replicate` to get the number of *rows* you want. Here, I've said make 5 rows.

```
set.seed(1)
y <- t(replicate(5, myFun()))
y
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
# [1,] 0.2193406 0.3074170 0.4732425
# [2,] 0.4522318 0.1004252 0.4473430
# [3,] 0.4227516 0.2957136 0.2815348
# [4,] 0.1390588 0.4635751 0.3973661
# [5,] 0.3731857 0.2086423 0.4181721
```

Verify that each row does, indeed add up to 1:

```
rowSums(y)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks!  I should have been more specific.  I'm trying to create an allocation table to use in a portfolio optimization program.  So the columns would be securities and each row is a different allocation.  Each row has to add up to 1 (or 100%) and I'd like to be able to specify the increments.  So for example, if there are three securities and I want the increment to be 1%, the first row could be 98%, 1%, 1%.  The next row could be 97%, 1%, 2% and so on.  In the end I'd have a large table with every possible allocation combination (based on a specified interval).  Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but...

It's not totally clear how you would like to determine the values of each column;  guessing from your sample, it looks like the values are a random sampling from `seq(0, 1, .25)` so long as the rows add up to `1`

```
set.seed(222)
vals <- seq(0, 1, .25)

TotalRows <- 12
TotalCols <- 3
Lim       <- 1

# First Column
myDF <- data.frame(sample(vals, TotalRows, TRUE))

# Each next column, except last
for (i in 2:(TotalCols-1))
    myDF[, i] <- apply(myDF, 1, function(x) sample(vals[vals + sum(x) <= Lim], 1))

# Last column is difference from Lim (ie, from 1)
myDF[, TotalCols] <- apply(myDF, 1, function(x) Lim - sum(x) )

# Set Colnames if needed
colnames(myDF) <- paste0("Col", 1:TotalCols)

# Total Column if needed
myDF[, "TOTAL"] <- apply(myDF, 1, sum)

myDF

 #     Col1 Col2 Col3 TOTAL
 #  1  1.00 0.00 0.00     1
 #  2  0.00 0.75 0.25     1
 #  3  0.50 0.50 0.00     1
 #  4  0.00 0.00 1.00     1
 #  5  1.00 0.00 0.00     1
 #  6  1.00 0.00 0.00     1
 #  7  0.25 0.00 0.75     1
 #  8  0.50 0.00 0.50     1
 #  9  0.50 0.50 0.00     1
 #  10 0.00 0.25 0.75     1
 #  11 0.50 0.00 0.50     1
 #  12 0.00 0.50 0.50     1
```

---

As a nice function:

```
# example call:
creatTable(TotalRows=12, TotalCols=8)

# definition:
creatTable <- function(TotalRows, TotalCols, Lim=1, vals=seq(0, 1, .25), columnPrfx="Col")  {
  myDF <- data.frame(sample(vals, TotalRows, TRUE))
  for (i in 2:(TotalCols-1))
      myDF[, i] <- apply(myDF, 1, function(x) sample(vals[vals + sum(x) <= Lim], 1))
  myDF[, TotalCols] <- apply(myDF, 1, function(x) Lim - sum(x) )
  colnames(myDF) <- paste0(columnPrfx, 1:TotalCols)
  myDF[, "TOTAL"] <- apply(myDF, 1, sum)
}
```